# Get Local time zone date by date component

Tags: ios, swift, date

Ok, this is my codes for format the current date to GMT format and return the value in date type. I 'po' the nowComponent variable while debugging which shows me the current local time zone values but the block of code 'calendar.date(from: nowComponents)!' still return me a UTC date. How to get the Date in local timezone ?

```
    var nowComponents = DateComponents()
    let date = Date()

    nowComponents.year = (calendar as NSCalendar).component(NSCalendar.Unit.year, from: date)
    nowComponents.month = (calendar as NSCalendar).component(NSCalendar.Unit.month, from: date)
    nowComponents.day = (calendar as NSCalendar).component(NSCalendar.Unit.day, from: date)
    nowComponents.hour = (calendar as NSCalendar).component(NSCalendar.Unit.hour, from: date)
    nowComponents.minute = (calendar as NSCalendar).component(NSCalendar.Unit.minute, from: date)
    nowComponents.second = (calendar as NSCalendar).component(NSCalendar.Unit.second, from: date)

    (nowComponents as NSDateComponents).timeZone = TimeZone.current

    return calendar.date(from: nowComponents)!
```

Comment: i used the dateFormatter to convert the date to local time zone and it is worked ! but i like to use the calendar.current or calendar.date to achieve the date conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of your code is necessary. The line:

```
let date = Date()
```

is all you need. This gives you the current date and time.

Your mistake is using `po` to print the date. This uses the `description` method on the date which shows the debug output of the date and that output shows the date in UTC time.

If you want to see the date, as a string, in local time, use `DateFormatter`:

```
let df = DateFormatter()
df.dateStyle = .long
df.timeStyle = .long
let str = df.string(from: date)
print(str)
```

This will show the date in local time.

Comment: thank. as i mentioned the dateFormatter is worked but it format the date to string. Actually i like to get the value in date type. Convert 'str' to date object again ?

Comment: There's no need. A date is a date. It doesn't have a format.

Comment: perhaps i misunderstood the date conversion. I thought a date object can be UTC(default) format and GMT format. from your explanation, a date type object is always displayed in UTC, right? If i want to get the GMT date value then i need to do DateFormatter. 

Because i tried to add 'hours' to a date that change the value from  '03 April 2017 11:50 PM' (GMT) to '04 April 2017 2:50AM' (GMT) but when i read the date variable for further process and it return me '03 April 2017' date because it is a UTC format. I expected the date is '04 April 2017'...

Comment: A `Date` has no display until it is converted to a `String` using a `DateFormatter`. When you log a date, that is what actually happens. The date is converted to a string and that string is only shown in the UTC timezone. You don't need to do any conversions or changes.